# Brushing, flossing, and mouth wash

Tags: brushing-teeth, mouthwash, toothbrush, rinsing-mouth, floss-flossing

If a person had to choose only 1 method of oral hygiene, what would be the most effective for achieve health gums and teeth:
1- brushing with toothpaste
2- flossing
3- rinsing with mouth wash

Comment: It isn't difficult to do some research and present what you've found when asking here; doing so would be helpful in getting a response.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Knowing what you know about brushing, flossing, and mouth wash, can you share why one might be the best? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a hypothetical question actually... I'm surprised those are even allowed in this community/site.  I'd go with number 1 and number 2 BOTH...  Please give a reason other than hypothetically why you would only be able to do one of the three.

Answer (score 4):

**From a medical/dental standpoint, flossing *and* brushing** with or without toothpaste is the best way of eliminating plaque, which can cause cavities and gum disease.

**For the philosophical aspect of your question**:
If you had to chose between the two (and you should be doing both!), I would **floss**, since floss reaches more easily between the teeth than the toothbrush, while being able to remove plaque on the surfaces of the tooth which the tooth brush can reach.

*Mouthwashes are not useful without prior mechanical removal of plaque*.

---

It should be noted that your question was already somewhat answered in another post: [Is brushing teeth without toothpaste actually harmful?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/is-brushing-teeth-without-toothpaste-actually-harmful/1366#1366)

---

References:

- http://www.aapd.org/assets/1/25/Axelsson-03-S1.pdf