# Is there by any way to 'remotely' brush teeth

Tags: dentistry, brushing-teeth, toothpaste, mouthwash, toothbrush

As the title stated, is there any way we can get our teeth clean (like we brushed it) without physical contact of us with our teeth?

Or is there anyway to get our teeth clean in less than 3 minutes (which is the average time one takes to brush one's teeth)?

Comment: Like using UV to kill the bacteria? There are a lot of dentists and researchers in the world, I'm sure if they found a way for you to brush your teeth more efficiently then they would have found it, packaged it, marketed it and sold it for $49.99

Comment: Dentists commonly use ultrasound (ultrasonic scalers) to clean teeth. While they may still be sticking a tool into your mouth and presumably scraping off plaque, ultrasound vibrations actually aid in removing plaque and biofilms from your teeth. Probably not what you're imagining though. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasonic_cleaning

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is **NO**

The long answer is: **If time is of concern, ask your oral health professional whether an electric toothbrush can improve your cleaning enough so that 2 minutes of brushing are sufficient.**

As stated in another question on Health.Stackexchange:

> it is the physical movement of the bristles of the brush that removes
>   plaque that accumulates on and between the teeth and gums.

**No matter what tool you use, contact is unavoidable with the teeth.**

I currently have not seen good scientific papers that endorse using high-pressure water or air as a substitute for a toothbrush and floss to clean teeth.

Here is an article that discusses plaque control using a toothbrush:
http://www.aapd.org/assets/1/25/Axelsson-03-S1.pdf

The Health.Stackexchange question I sited from:
[Is brushing teeth without toothpaste actually harmful?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/is-brushing-teeth-without-toothpaste-actually-harmful/1366#1366)